# Checkboxes are not working in todo in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm implementing Todo with checkboxes. I have a id,content,status properties in the state.
Status has 3 states(pending,done, deleted). There is a checkbox for the todolist. If the status is pending then checkbox shouldn't be checked. If the status is done then checkbox should be checked.By default, status is pending.Checkbox should be checked/unchecked according to the status. On deleting the todo then status should be updated to deleted. Now I'm struck with checkbox implementation. It's not working as per the requirement.

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';
import AddTodo from './AddTodo';

class App extends React.Component{
  state={
   todos:[
   {id:1,content:'Buy milk1',status:'pending'},
   {id:2, content:'buy carrots1', status: 'pending'},
   {id:3,content:'Buy milk2',status:'done'},
   {id:4, content:'buy carrots2', status: 'deleted'}
  ]
}
onDelete=(id)=>{
 const todo = this.state.todos.find((todoItem => todoItem.id === id))
 todo.status ='deleted';
 this.setState([...this.state.todos]);
}
onChangeCheckbox=(id, checked)=>{ 
 const todo = this.state.todos.find((todoItem => todoItem.id === id))
 if(checked){
  todo.status = 'done'
 }
 else{
  todo.status = 'pending'
 }
 this.setState([...this.state.todos]);
 }
addTodo=(todo)=>{
 todo.id=Math.random();
 todo.status = "pending";
 let todos=[...this.state.todos,todo];
 this.setState({todos});
}
render(){
 return(
  <div>
    <h1>Todo's App</h1>
    
    <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
    <Todo todos={this.state.todos} deleteTodo={this.onDelete} onChangeCheckbox= 
    {this.onChangeCheckbox} />
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default App;
```

AddTodo.js :

```
  import React from 'react';

class AddTodo extends React.Component{
  state={
    content:''
  }

 handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
        content:e.target.value
    });
 }
 handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addTodo(this.state);
    this.setState({
        content:''
    })
  }
 render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type='text' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.content} 
                 placeholder="Enter todo" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
 }
 export default AddTodo;
```

Todo.js:

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';

 const Todo=({todos,deleteTodo, onChangeCheckbox})=>{
   const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

   const handleInputChange =(event,id,status)=>{
    setChecked(status=='pending' ? !checked: checked) 
    onChangeCheckbox(id,!checked);
 }
 const todoList=todos.length ? (

    todos.map(todo=>{
        return(
            <div key={todo.id}>
                {(todo.status === 'pending' || todo.status === 'done' )&& (
                        <div>
                            {/* <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={checked}
                                onChange={(event)=>handleInputChange(event,todo.id)}
                            /> */}
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={todo.status === 'pending' ? checked : !checked}
                                onChange= 
                         {(event)=>handleInputChange(event,todo.id,todo.status)}
                            />
                            <p style={todo.status =='pending'? {color:'red'}: 
                      {color:'green',textDecoration:'line-through'}} >
                                {todo.content}
                            </p>
                            <button onClick={()=>deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        )
    })
  ):(
    <p>You have no todos</p>
  );
 return(
    <div>
        {todoList}
    </div>
  )
 }
 export default Todo;
```

Thanks in advance.. Please find the codesandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ganguly-0r054?file=/src/Todo.js

Comment: If you provide your code in a sandbox that will be helpful to tackle your issue.

Comment: "It's not working as per the requirement." It isn't our job to debug your entire codebase. What debugging have you tried? Is there an error? Can you specifically say what part of your code isn't meeting the spec? Provide a set of reproduction steps? We need something more than "it's not working".

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar : https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ganguly-0r054?file=/src/Todo.js

Comment: You don't need any extra "checked" state at all since you can completely derive any checked value from the todo status. Provided working solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few issues with your code. The biggest concern is the state mutations in your `onDelete`, `onChangeCheckbox`, and `addTodo` handlers. These handlers also incorrectly don't store the `todos` array.

Use functional state updates and map the existing state todos array to a new array, and copy the `todo` item that matches by id so you are not mutating state objects.

Math.random generates floating point numbers, and as such, makes it ***extremely*** difficult to compare with `===`. I added a guid to each instead.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { id: uuidV4(), content: "Buy milk1", status: "pending" },
      { id: uuidV4(), content: "buy carrots1", status: "pending" },
      { id: uuidV4(), content: "Buy milk2", status: "done" },
      { id: uuidV4(), content: "buy carrots2", status: "deleted" }
    ]
  };

  onDelete = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id
          ? {
              ...todo,
              status: "deleted"
            }
          : todo
      )
    }));
  };

  onChangeCheckbox = (id, checked) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id
          ? {
              ...todo,
              status: checked ? "done" : "pending"
            }
          : todo
      )
    }));
  };

  addTodo = (todo) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos: [
        ...prevState.todos,
        {
          ...todo,
          id: uuidV4(),
          status: "pending"
        }
      ]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Todo's App</h1>

        <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
        <Todo
          todos={this.state.todos}
          deleteTodo={this.onDelete}
          onChangeCheckbox={this.onChangeCheckbox}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There is also no need to store any `checked` state in `Todo.js` as the checked state is easily derived from your `todo.status` property. If the status is "done" then check the box.

You can (should) run your `todos` array through a filter first to remove the deleted status todos.

```
const Todo = ({ todos, deleteTodo, onChangeCheckbox }) => {
  const todoList = todos.length ? (
    todos
      .filter(({ status }) => status !== "deleted")
      .map((todo) => {
        return (
          <div key={todo.id}>
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={todo.status === "done"}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  onChangeCheckbox(todo.id, event.target.checked)
                }
              />
              <p
                style={
                  todo.status === "pending"
                    ? { color: "red" }
                    : { color: "green", textDecoration: "line-through" }
                }
              >
                {todo.content}
              </p>
              <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      })
  ) : (
    <p>You have no todos</p>
  );
  return <div>{todoList}</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit checkboxes-are-not-working-in-todo-in-react-js]

Answer (score 1):

You have only one `checked` state, for every `todo` item.
I'd recommend for you to add `checked` state to every item in `todos` list.
Then you can find item and change state accordingly

Answer (score 1):

that's happen because you let the checked status listen to the `current component state` and not to the item status. and they are not in sync. so you have two solutions. first pass status value as props to the checked state to let the state changed when the status value updated and i think it is more expensive. I have other suggestion without the state at all.

```
 // const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false); remove that, you no longer need it

 const handleInputChange =(event,id,status)=>{ 
   let isChecked = status=='pending' ? true: false;
   onChangeCheckbox(id, isChecked);
 }
```

also update the input check status

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={todo.status === 'pending' ? false : true}
    onChange= {(event)=>handleInputChange(event,todo.id,todo.status)}
 />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hugle-jn22o?file=/src/Todo.js